# Selecting data from a sub query

Tags: sql-server, subquery, order-by

I am doing the exercises this is the link (https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/sql/exercises/standard/subqueries/4228/).
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance!

### Question

Write a `SELECT` statement to return events from the 3 continents with the fewest events.

### Help

To do this first write a `SELECT` query which returns all the continents and events.

#### Subquery select

Unsorted results returns 459 events.

Now underneath write another `SELECT` statement which lists events for the 3 continents with the lowest `COUNT` of events. Put the `COUNT` in the `ORDER BY` clause, not the `SELECT`.

Finally use the second `SELECT` as a filter in the first `SELECT`'s `WHERE` clause. To do this use `ContinentName IN (subquery)`.

#### Subquery Continent

Only 8 events in these 3 continents - maybe stick to Ibiza and the Islands!

### My query

```
Select [ContinentName], [EventName] 
from tblevent a 
join[dbo].[tblCountry] c on a.[CountryID]=c.[CountryID] 
join [dbo].[tblContinent] b on c.[ContinentID]=b.[ContinentID]
where [ContinentName] in
(
  select top 3 [ContinentName] 
  from tblevent a join[dbo].[tblCountry] c  on a.[CountryID]=c.[CountryID] 
  join [dbo].[tblContinent] b on c.[ContinentID]=b.[ContinentID]
  group by [ContinentName] 
) 
order by count([EventName])
```

Result:

[image]

Error message when I run above query:

> Column 'dbo.tblContinent.ContinentName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The problem goes away if I remove the `order by count([EventName])` but I need events from 3 continents with the fewest events, so `order by count([EventName])` must be there. There is some other problem causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to using `COUNT()` in a query without `GROUP BY` - which means `GROUP BY ()` - and at the same time having some columns in the `SELECT` list. You need to move that `COUNT()` in the subquery.

Assuming you want to show all Events from the 3 continents with lowest count of events:

```
Select c.[ContinentName], a.[EventName] 
from tblevent a 
     join [dbo].[tblCountry] c
       on a.[CountryID] = c.[CountryID] 
     join [dbo].[tblContinent] b
       on c.[ContinentID] = b.[ContinentID]
where [ContinentName] in
(
  select top 3 [ContinentName]
  from tblevent a 
       join [dbo].[tblCountry] c
         on a.[CountryID] = c.[CountryID] 
       join [dbo].[tblContinent] b
         on c.[ContinentID] = b.[ContinentID]
  group by [ContinentName]
  order by count(*) 
)  ;
```